# How do I remove this metal grating-type thing from a coffee table?

Tags: metal

I want to remove this lower part of my coffee table so I can sit down and put my legs under the table.
How do I remove it cleanly?
(I'm a home improvement newb, I have basic power tools but never worked with metal before)

picture 1 is the coffee table

picture 2 is the underside of where the metal thing connects to a leg
[image: coffee table]

[image: what it looks at the joint from the underside]

Comment: Is that a real granite top? If it is, don't remove that grating. The frame around that grating is likely a structural feature of that table. Also, there aren't really any "clean" ways to break a weld. You'll just have to go at it with a grinder and refinish the the bare metal that results from all the grinding.

Comment: Agreed, except to me that looks more like concrete than granite. But definitely some form of "really heavy stuff that is likely relying on the grating to keep the legs from bending".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picture 2 shows it's held on to the legs by a pretty crappy weld. My first thought is "hit it with a hammer" because that weld should be reasonably easy to break; but you run a risk for collateral damage to the leg (bending or twisting) or the rest of the table, that you want to keep.

The proper and clean way to remove that would be with a Dremel or an angle grinder. That way you can target the weld and grind the leg smooth again after it's removed, but you'll need to repaint at least that bare-metal area when you're done, and possibly the whole leg if you have trouble matching paint.

I agree with what ScienceGeyser said though, this bottom grate could be structural in a pretty heavy table and removing it might cause it to be incredibly unstable.

Comment: So there's no such thing as heating it up with a welding machine and melting the weld to soften it and pull it off? With metal you always need to cut?

Comment: That;'s what you do with *solder* - which uses a low melting point metal to connect two high melting point metals (essentially). With welding, the metals being joined are actually melted together - which is *much* stronger, but which also requires a much higher temperature.

Comment: @LarryWood wood, yes the is, it's called a plasma cutter or oxy-acetylene cutter (AKA gas-axe)  but since a weld is made of the same metal as the base metal everything melts at the same temperature.  for plebs without the funds and skills to wield such a "fire-gun" against steel, a $15 angle grinder will do the trick with less risk of collateral damage. a $5 file would probably work too if you're persistent enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is welded . The only rational way to remove it is with a portable grinder ,probably an angle grinder. It will be a significant job and require repainting the bare steel and possible the whole table for a professional job.